# Async Validation in Angular model based form can't convert null to object

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I'm trying to do an async validation on a model based form in angular. For simplicity I have removed all other fields of the form. In the actual example there are more fields.

```
buildForm(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      'username': 
        [this.user.username, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)],
            [this.validateUsernameUnique.bind(this)]]
    });
    this.registerForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
    this.onValueChanged();  // set validation messages now
  }
```

the `validateUsernameUnique()` method should call a service and remotely check if a username already exists and return true or false. The service is working properly, its result appear on the console as expected.

```
validateUsernameUnique(control: AbstractControl) {
    clearTimeout(this.usernameCheckTimeout);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.usernameCheckTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (control.value.length >= 4) {
          this.userService.doesUsernameExist(control.value)
            .then(res => {
              if (!res) {
                resolve(null);
              } else {
                resolve({nameTaken: true});
              }
            });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to skip this validation until the value is >= 4, because I want the `minLength(4)`-Validation to show up until then.

The validation messages are defined like this:

```
formErrors = {
    'username': ''
};
validationMessages = {
    'username': {
      'required': 'username is required',
      'minlength': 'username must be at least 4 characters long',
      'nameTaken': 'username does already exist'
    }
};
```

The minLength()-Checks works at the beginning as expected and `username must be at least 4 characters long` shows up on the form too. But when I reach 4 characters, I get an exception in the console:

`TypeError: can't convert null to object
Stack trace:
UserRegisterComponent.prototype.onValueChanged@webpack-internal:///./src/app/user/user-register/user-register.component.ts:111:39
UserRegisterComponent.prototype.buildForm/<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/user/user-register/user-register.component.ts:63:49`

After the error occured, no validation message is displayed anymore, the minLength-Validation doesn't also work anymore.

The stackTrack reported the problem in `onValueChanged():111`, this method looks like this:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
   if (!this.registerForm) {
     return;
   }
   const form = this.registerForm;
   for (const field of  Object.keys(this.formErrors)) {
     // clear previous error message (if any)
     this.formErrors[field] = '';
     const control = form.get(field);
     if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
       const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
       for (const key of Object.keys(control.errors)) {
         this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

- How can I get synchronous and async validations get to work side by side? I got the approach with a async-Validation-Method in the same component as the form also from SO.
- How can I get the `nameTaken`-errorMessage to appear on the form? Is `resolve({nameTaken: true});` in the validation Promise the wrong approach?

Any input appreciated. Don't know exactly how I can possibly debug the currenct behaviour to get a idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There also appears to be a mistake in `validateUsernameUnique()`. You type `return this.userService.doesUsernameExist(control.value).then()...` which will return out of the function before the request is complete.

Try without the `return` before `this.userService.doesUsernameExist(...)`.

If you still get the error, I'm guessing it is from trying to call `Object.keys()` on null. Check what the value of `control.errors` is before doing `Object.keys(control.errors)`

Comment: removed the return from `doesUsernameExist()`, buy it doesn't change anything on the behavior. edited code above.

Comment: it's indeed `control.errors`, which is causing the null exception. I changed the for-of-loop back to a for-in-loop and changed the else block of validate..() now to `this.formErrors['username'] += this.validationMessages['username']['nameTaken'] + ' '; resolve(null);` and then the code works as expected and shows the error message. but I think this is just an ugly workaround. Is there a way I can pass that message to `onValueChanged()` like the sync-Validators? or what is the best practice for something like this?

Comment: I only used a for-of-loop because it appears the TSLint wants that since the newest version of Typescript. Should I ignore this TSLint-error in this case?

Comment: Why not simple add `&& this.control.errors` to your if condition (`if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid)`)?

Comment: ok, that fixed the problem will null, thanks. and how should I call onValueChanged() after the Promise finished? this method does only get called after the sync-validators finished. see my ugly workaround in the second comment. or should I leave it this way and `resolve(null)`?

Comment: You should be able to do that by refactoring your code into a new function.

Move the logic inside your `onValueChanged()` function into a new function called `updateErrorMessages()` or something. Then simply call `updateErrorMessages()` inside `onValueChanged()` and your validator.